# How to dynamic change background image depends on route in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new here and starting with React JS.
Can someone help me with dynamic change background img depends on route? So, to be precise...I am building recipe app and I want to change background image depends on category. So I wanted to do it with useParams() but it's not working.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function HeaderPicture() {
    let params = useParams();
    let headerPicture = "";

    if(params.name == "/cuisine/Fingerfood") {
        headerPicture = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598449426314-8b02525e8733?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1026&q=80"
    }

    else {
        headerPicture = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605851868183-7a4de52117fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80"
    }

    return(
        <div className='top-picture' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${headerPicture})` }}>
            <h1>Text1</h1>
            <h3>Text2</h3>
        </div>
    )  
}

export default HeaderPicture
```

It always shows the second picture so it seems that first if() for some reason is not working as it should.
Here are the routes and they are working fine. All components shows as they sholud.

```
<Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/cuisine/:type" element={<Cuisine />} />
          <Route path="/searched/:search" element={<Searched />} />
          <Route path="/recipe/:name" element={<Recipe />} />
          <Route path="/diet/:mediterranian" element={<Mediterranian />} />
      </Routes>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use `useState` when trying to manipulate the DOM and `useEffect` to avoid side effect like so

```
import {
    useParams
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function HeaderPicture() {
    let params = useParams();
    let [headerPicture, setHeaderPicture] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        if (params.name == "/cuisine/Fingerfood") {
            setHeaderPicture("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598449426314-8b02525e8733?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1026&q=80")
        } else {
            setHeaderPicture("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605851868183-7a4de52117fa?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80")
        }

    }, [params.name]);

    return ( 
        <div className='top-picture'
        style = {
            {
                backgroundImage: `url(${headerPicture})`
            }
        }>
        <h1> Text1 </h1> 
        <h3> Text2 </h3> 
        </div>
    )
}

export default HeaderPicture
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle dynamic route params, you need to replace this line:

```
if(params.name == "/cuisine/Fingerfood") {
```

with this:

```
if (params.type === "Fingerfood") {
```

since your parameter is named as `type` in your routes.

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-use-params?file=/src/HeaderPicture.js) for a live working example of this solution.